# how do I pass a URI to jitsi or libjitsi from Java?

Tags: java, api, sip, command-line-interface, jitsi

Jitsi has a CLI interface:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ jitsi --help
Jitsi 2.4.4997
Usage: jitsi [OPTIONS] [uri-to-call]
```

which is somewhat similar to Skype:

https://askubuntu.com/a/492115/45156

That being said, is there a more "java" way to interact with jitsi to pass it a URI to call?

The only documented way to do so with Jitsi is to do this from the command line?